# scraping web vba extract value of "src" attribute

Tags: excel, vba, extract, screen-scraping, src

I have the following html string

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff" class="border_top">
<td>10:30</td>
<td>-24<br><img src="cup.gif" width="14" height="14"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="/flags/GE.gif" width="28" height="19"></td>
<td><b><a href="/FC-Gagra/4562/">Gagra</a></b> <font face="Verdana" 
  style="font-size:14px" color="#ff0000">↓</font> <br> <a href="/Torpedo- 
  Kutaisi/1857/">Kutaisi</a> <img src="star.gif" align="abscenter" 
  width="10" height="10"> <font face="Verdana" style="font-size:14px" 
  color="#006600">↑</font> </td>
<td align="center"><b>2.75</b></td>
<td align="center">3.10</td><td align="center">2.35</td>
</tr>
```

and I just want the value of "src"

**/flags/GE.gif**

from vba I try to take the value of src as follows:

```
Set td = tr.getElementsBytagName("td")
camp =td.getattribute("src")(1)
```

but it gives me error:

**property or method not supported by the object**

Comment: What have you tried and researched? Answer for this exists on SO and should be fairly easy to find.

Comment: thanks, i have tried `getattribute("src")`
but it gives me error: "property or method not supported by the object"

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried and what happened using [edit] please?

Comment: `getElementsBytagName` return a collection of elements, not a single element, so you need to index into that e.g. `td(2)`.  Also `src` is not an attribute of the `td` element, but of the contained `img`.

Comment: so i modified the vba script
`Set td = tr.getelementsBytagName("td")
  Set img = td(2).getelementsBytagName("IMG")(0)`
  **camp = img.classname**

Comment: And?  Did that work?

Comment: `Dim gifSource As String` Get the pic link string directly with `gifSource = tr.getElementsByTagName("img")(1).src` Can't say anymore because you don't show more html. The best is to post the url.

Comment: `gifSource = tr.getElementsByTagName("img")(1).src` this was the solution, Thanks @Zwenn .
I still have to learn differences between tags, attributes, values and other similar things. Many thanks, you are the most valuable community on the web